# Mockito verify() fails with "too many actual invocations"

Tags: java, mockito

I have a fairly involved test case I am trying to add the following verify() to:

```
verify(userService).getUserById(anyLong()).setPasswordChangeRequired(eq(Boolean.TRUE));
```

This fails with this error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
userService.getUserById(<any>);
Wanted 1 time:
-> at     test.controllers.AuthenticationControllerMockTest.testLookupsExceeded(AuthenticationControllerMockTest.java:404)
But was 4 times. Undesired invocation:
```

So I changed it to this:

```
verify(userService, atLeastOnce()).getUserById(anyLong()).setPasswordChangeRequired(eq(Boolean.TRUE));
```

And now it fails with:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.controllers.AuthenticationControllerMockTest.testLookupsExceeded(AuthenticationControllerMockTest.java:404)
```

because this is returning null:

```
verify(userService, atLeastOnce()).getUserById(anyLong())
```

This seems puzzling - If I use the default (one invocation only), it fails because it's being invoked multiple times, but if I tell it that multiple invocations are OK, it fails because it can't find any invocations!

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Did you try using a specific number? `verify(userService, times(4))...`

Comment: This comment is actually the best answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It looks like you both want to mock what happens when `userService.getUserById()` is called, and also verify that `setPasswordChangeRequired(true)` is called on that returned object.

You can accomplish this with something like:

```
UserService userService = mock(UserService.class);
User user = mock(User.class);
when(userService.getUserById(anyLong())).thenReturn(user);

...

// invoke the method being tested

...

verify(user).setPasswordChangeRequired(true);
```

Comment: Thanks!  The mocking stuff is a little new to me but you helped a lot.  And thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 12):

Adding the number of times you are calling the method should also resolve the issue.

> verify(aclient, times(2)).someMethod();

Answer (score 3):

Getting the same error intermittently. We found that we added two `@Mock`s with the same type in the class by mistake.

```
@Mock
SomeClient aClient;

@Mock
SomeClient bClient;


@Test
void test(){
  verify(aClient).someMethod(any());  //passes and fails intermittently
}
```

Removing the second mock fixed the flakiness.